# Sql Query to edit full url ignoring section

Tags: mysql, sql

There is anyway I can edit an url but only the base?
For example:
I have something like this

`src="www.example.site/media/folder/image-name.jpg"`

and I need to change that url in all tables that it exists

`src="{{media url=/folder/image-name.jpg}}"`

Any way to do a query that does that?

Edit:

Sorry I didn't explained very well.
The change of the base url doesn't give errors, the main problem if after the image-name, que base url is always the same that I can change but I can't get a solution to add the }} at the end because the image-name is not always the same.

Thanks :D

Comment: your question could use a bit of clarification. MySQL has a REPLACE(fullstring, what_to_replace, replacement) function. is that what you are looking for? that only replaces within one table. typically, you can't do one query on multiple tables at the same time.

Comment: I edited to add clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your base URL is always same and image is in .jpg ( off course you can change thew code to check .png or any other file formats as well), this code should be able to replace the old image location to new image.

```
declare @magento_field nvarchar(max) = 'ABCD.....10000bank19901005statement20191010...www.example.site/media/folder/image-name.jpg.....dwgyhh',
        @base_url nvarchar(max) = 'www.example.site/media/',
        @image_folder nvarchar(max) = 'folder/image-name1.jpg'


Select @magento_field,
       LEFT(suffix_after_base_url,CHARINDEX('.jpg',suffix_after_base_url)+3) as current_image_location,
       new_image_location,
       (prefix_before_base_url + url_part + new_image_location + part_after_image_location) as new_magento_field           
from(Select @magento_field as magento_field,        
            @base_url as base_url,
            @image_folder as new_image_location,
     LEFT(@magento_field,CHARINDEX(@base_url,@magento_field)-1) as prefix_before_base_url,
     CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@magento_field,CHARINDEX(@base_url,@magento_field),23) = @base_url
          THEN SUBSTRING(@magento_field,CHARINDEX(@base_url,@magento_field),23)
          ELSE @magento_field 
          END as url_part,
     RIGHT(@magento_field,LEN(@magento_field) - 
     CHARINDEX(@base_url,@magento_field)-22) as suffix_after_base_url,
     RIGHT(@magento_field,LEN(@magento_field) - 
     CHARINDEX('.jpg',@magento_field)-3) as part_after_image_location
   ) A
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to clarify my problem, the main problem resides at the end of the image-name.

Comment: do you want to create a new column of string data that is = {{media url=/folder/image-name.jpg}}" whenever the base url of src is "www.example.site/media/

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say maybe an important thing, that url I need to change is in a field with lots of text it's a block from magento in this case so it has all the text in it and in the middle of it there are those urls

Comment: Thanks. But im not used to make querys only simple ones on phpMyAdmin so, if it isn't much to ask, can you clarify what does what in the query and why do that why if there is any other? I would like to understand it :D Sorry and thanks you so much for all the time and help!

Comment: What I am really doing is breaking it into parts. So 1. we get a big text field from magento 2. we search for the base url in the text 3. Then we search for the part that has image folder an name. 4. We replace that part and join back all the other parts to make a new magento field. (prefix_before_base_url + url_part + new_image_location + part_after_image_location) as new_magento_field

Comment: Okok I think I get it, but it can be used in phpMyAdmin? What do I need to change?
And is this going to run through all the entries and edit the url in all of then?

Comment: If you have the ability to do it in mysql then you can use the piece of code. If you want to do it in php then you should tag the question with php. google this  : substring in php and replicate the logic there.

Comment: I can do it in command line no problem, just used to use de php but no problem, I only need to know what do I need to edit there like @magento_field is the table name right?

Comment: @megnto_field is the name of the block/field based on your comment - that url I need to change is in a field with lots of text it's a block from magento in this case so it has all the text in it and in the middle of it there are those urls

Answer (score 0):

If using php you can assign the partial url to a variable:

```
$partialUrl="www.example.site/media/";
```

Then while outputting you can do:

```
src="<?php echo $partialUrl;?>/folder/image-name.jpg"
```

If it is pure SQL, you can create a table partial urls, with two columns: `name` and `url`. Then get the url:

```
quer_for_url = "SELECT `url` FROM `partialUrls` where `name`='urlone'";
```